# How should I approach HTML coding of an outline with Roman numerals, numbers, alpha letters?

Tags: html, css

What is the proper HTML formatting for a typical content outline using Roman numerals, numbers, alpha letters, etc.? Say I have three main top-level sections Roman Numerals I, II and III. Each of them have two sub topics A. and B. each of them have between 2 and 4 sub-sub topics 1) through 4). Is there any known hack to accomplish the correct indents or is it all by hand, section by section?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the CSS ordered-list sub-property `list-style-type` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type)).

Specifically

```
list-style-type: decimal
list-style-type: upper-roman
list-style-type: upper-alpha
```

Then simply shain the selectors

```
ol {} //top level numbers
ol > li > ol {} //sub level roman
ol > li > ol > li > ol {} //sub sub level letters
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most simple way to accomplish what you're trying to do, with some example code.

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: upper-roman;
}
ol ol {
  list-style-type: upper-alpha;
}
ol ol ol {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    list point
    <ol>
      <li>
        list point
        <ol>
          <li>list point</li>
          <li>list point</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        list point
        <ol>
          <li>list point</li>
          <li>list point</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        list point
        <ol>
          <li>list point</li>
          <li>list point</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    list point
    <ol>
      <li>
        list point
        <ol>
          <li>list point</li>
          <li>list point</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        list point
        <ol>
          <li>list point</li>
          <li>list point</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        list point
        <ol>
          <li>list point</li>
          <li>list point</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    list point
    <ol>
      <li>
        list point
        <ol>
          <li>list point</li>
          <li>list point</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        list point
        <ol>
          <li>list point</li>
          <li>list point</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        list point
        <ol>
          <li>list point</li>
          <li>list point</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    list point
    <ol>
      <li>
        list point
        <ol>
          <li>list point</li>
          <li>list point</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        list point
        <ol>
          <li>list point</li>
          <li>list point</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        list point
        <ol>
          <li>list point</li>
          <li>list point</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```